Apache APISIX in Standalone mode - route wildcards for path segments
I'm new to Apache APISIX and have it running in a Docker container in "standalone" mode, as described here:
https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/2.15/stand-alone/
As per the article, I have the configuration defined in conf/apisix.yaml.  I have the following configuration to define a route:
routes:
  - uri: /v1/endpoint
    methods: [POST]
    service_id: myserviceid

I'd like a another route defined that matches some ID values nested in the uri.  e.g.
/v1/endpoint/123/something/456
/v1/endpoint/789/something/876

I've got this to work with * wildcards, which will allow ANYTHING to be present in the path segments.
  - uri: /v1/endpoint/*/something/*

I'd like this to be more restrictive because these rules allow other / characters to be present in the wildcard parts.  The following URLs are matched by this rule, but I don't want them to be:
/v1/endpoint/blah/blah/something/blah/blah


Solution: radixtree_uri_with_parameter
You can enable router-radixtree with path parameters by setting apisix.router.http: radixtree_uri_with_parameter in conf/config.yaml:
# [...]

apisix:
  router:
    http: radixtree_uri_with_parameter

# [...]

This configuration allows you to use both * (any string) and path parameters in APISIX Route URIs.
Example
In your example, after setting the configuration above (remember to reload APISIX, e.g. with apisix reload), you can define the following route:
routes:
  - uri: /v1/endpoint/:id1/something/*
    methods: [POST]
    service_id: myserviceid

This route will match requests like:
/v1/endpoint/123/something/456
/v1/endpoint/789/something/876
/v1/endpoint/myEndpoint/something/
/v1/endpoint/myEndpoint456/something/foobar

And won't match, for example, requests like:
/v1/endpoint/blah/blah/something/blah/blah
/v1/endpoint/something/blah
/v1/endpoint//something/blah
/v1/endpoint/blah/something

For more information on APISIX routing configuration, see Router documentation.
Side Note
The library that APISIX uses to implement radixtree algorithm doesn't support path parameters that contain spaces   nor slashes /.
See issue api7/lua-resty-radixtree#148
